# Need assistance with an IF-statement

Tags: excel, vba

I have this cell which can not contain 0, a negative number a "dot" eg. 1.2, and can not be empty.

I have written the following code so far:

```
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Indata").Range("$C$9").Value = 0 Then
MsgBox "Var vänligen ange en höjd för pelaren som är större än 0"
Exit Sub
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Indata").Range("$C$9").Value < 0 Then MsgBox "Var vänligen ange en höjd för pelaren som är större än 0"
Exit Sub
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Indata").Range("$C$9").Value = "" Then MsgBox "Var vänligen ange en höjd för pelaren"
Exit Sub
End If
```

But the term: `If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Indata").Range("$C$9").Value = "" Then MsgBox "Var vänligen ange en höjd för pelaren"` does not work because when the cell C9 is empty the message `Var vänligen ange en höjd för pelaren som är större än 0`-appears, which is the wrong message.

I have not inserted the if-statement which prevents the user from inserting a dot sign and need some help on how to write it.

Would appreciate any kind of help, thank you.

/ Rinor

Comment: I see, thank you for this good information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the cell's value can be interpreted as a nullstring or as a 0. This is implicit based on the type of comparison you're doing.

When you are comparing an empty variant value to a number, there is an implied type conversion to avoid a mismatch error. Likewise, an empty variant when compared to a string is converted to nullstring.

Declare a variable as string to represent the contents of the cell.

```vb
Dim clValue as String

clValue = Cstr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Indata").Range("C9").Value)

If clValue = vbNullString Then 
    MsgBox "Var vänligen ange en höjd för pelaren"
    Exit Sub
End If
If clValue = "0" Then
    MsgBox "Var vänligen ange en höjd för pelaren som är större än 0"
    Exit Sub
End If
If CLng(clValue) < 0 Then 
    MsgBox "Var vänligen ange en höjd för pelaren som är större än 0"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

And add one more test to check for a dot/period/decimal:

```vb
If Instr(1, clValue, ".") <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "this cell cannot contain decimal numbers" 'Modify as needed
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Hi David, the code you helped me with worked very good. Thank you for the good explanation also!

/ Rinor

Comment: Cheers. Consider accepting one of these two answers if they have helped solve your problem.

Comment: Hi David, how can I accept an answer? I there a button to press?

Answer (score 1):

Place the test for **blank** as the first test of the three.

For example:

```
Sub ytrewq()
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Indata")
    If .Range("$C$9").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Var vänligen ange en höjd för pelaren"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If .Range("$C$9").Value = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Var vänligen ange en höjd för pelaren som är större än 0"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If .Range("$C$9").Value < 0 Then
        MsgBox "Var vänligen ange en höjd för pelaren som är större än 0"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Gary, could you help me on how to do that since I am new to macros?

Comment: Hi Gary, I tried yours and it worked good. I was missing the With-statement and therefore my code did not work. Thank you.